# Creating a new array from a slice of another in C

Tags: c, arrays, search, binary

I'm new to programming and I'm learning C. I'm trying to solve a problem by using recursion. I've found a lot of information about that and I could use it in my program but still I want to try something different. My question is as follows: I have

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n) 
// int value is value to search, 
// int values[] is the array in which value is to be found (or not)
// int n is size of array

// some code here and then:

       if (middle_number > value)
       {
           int new_array[] = values[0:middle_index];
           // I want my new array to be some slice of values[]
           // by declaring a range from 0 to the middle_index
           // Is that possible? 
           search(value, new_array, middle_index);
           // Using recursion 
       }
```

I could loop to create the new array, but then, I think, I would lose the advantages of binary search (better performance)

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Could I implement? new_array[] = values[0:middle_index] without using a loop?

Comment: You would get better performance by just working on the same array.  As you split up the array, just pass the array variable and the start and end indexes of the range you want to work on to your recursive function. There is no need to make copies of the array or any subset thereof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such direct array slicing feature for integer array is not supported in C language.
To implement binary search you can pass the array index to indicate the part of array to be used.

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int low, int high)
```

where low is lower index and high is higher array index to be used in the function code. you can even create int values[] as global variable and then use a search function as,

```
bool search(int value,int low, int high)
```

you can browse net and you'll get binary search implementation using this method since it is the common method of implementing binary search.

Comment: You can do it this way, but it involves an interface change that is actually unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In C, for the given problem, you use pointer arithmetic to bypass the problem altogether (there is no need for a copy of the array; you just search in a limited section of the array as if it was a copy of part of the array):

```
if (middle_number > value)
    return search(value, array + middle_index, n - middle_index);
```

There might be some adjustments to make to the argument list (of the ±1 variety), but the concept is that you pass the address of the middle element and the size of the top part of the array to the recursive call.

Plausible adjustments (because you know that `array[middle_index] != value`):

```
if (middle_number > value)
    return search(value, array + middle_index + 1, n - middle_index - 1);
```